# Reverse order BST Insertion

Tags: haskell

I was wondering if their is a way to insert list items in a BST from right to left. So far I can insert items from left to right.

**Code:**

```
-- Type constructor
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
   deriving (Eq, Show)

-- inserts into BST
insert :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
insert x Empty = Node x Empty Empty
insert x (Node y l r)
    | y == x = Node y l r
    | y < x = Node y l (insert x r)
    | y > x = Node y (insert x l) r

-- Converts list to a BST
listToTree :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Tree a
listToTree xs = foldl (\acc x -> insert x acc) Empty xs
```

What I'm currently achieving:

```
Prelude> listToTree [4,2,6]
Node 4 (Node 2 Empty Empty) (Node 6 Empty Empty)
```

But I wish the reverse order:

```
Node 6 (Node 2 Empty (Node 4 Empty Empty)) Empty
```

I'm not really sure how I can modify `foldl` to do this. Would a recursive approach be better for this sort of task? Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way is probably `listToTree xs = foldl (\acc x -> insert x acc) Empty $ reverse xs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious thing to do is to `reverse` the list before feeding it to `foldl`.  The same effect can be achieved by using `foldr`.

If you are asking how to modify the `insert` instruction itself, what you want is the last node inserted to be the root and whatever was there already to move down the tree. so:

```
insert x (Node y l r)  -- Note: x is the new value and y the existing root.
    | y == x = Node y l r -- Don't insert a dup (per original)
    | y > x = Node x l (insert y r) -- make x the new root and y goes in the left tree
    | y < x = Node x (insert y l) r  -- make x the new root and y goes in the right tree
```